# React - dropdown menu hover closes too fast

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have this dropdown menu and it has a gap between parent and child selector. which is causing it to close fast.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GeekOnGadgets/2jfqeos0/11/)

```
render() {
    return (
        <div class="dropdown-wrapper">
            <div class="image">Image</div>
            <ul class="dropdown-container">
                <li class="dropdown-list">Nothing</li>
                <li class="dropdown-list">Help</li>
                <li class="dropdown-list">Settings</li>
                <li class="dropdown-list">Logout</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

I tried few things.

1. using react onMoverOver and onMouseOut, which results in same behaviour
2. Changing css
3. Tried using jquery

How can I solve this problem. Any indication what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`margin-top: 0;` on `.dropdown-container` -- Because you have a margin on the `.dropdown-container` div, as soon as you move off the `.image` div you are no longer hovering over it... so the dropdown closes.

[Fiddle update](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/2jfqeos0/8/)

If you *want* space.. add it to the `.image` class...

`.dropdown-wrapper > .image { padding-bottom: 15px; }`

[Fiddle Update](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/2jfqeos0/10/)

Comment: I have a image with fix height and width  adding padding won't help and adding margin results into same behaviour

Comment: Then you need to show **complete, and minimal code** to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The problem is you want the menu to appear when you hover over an element... but you are moving the element (menu) off of the hover element too far. `margin-top:0;` fixes the issue. You may want to consider wrapping the menu in another div with no margin, and then trigger the drop down on *that* unmoved div.